# exception occurred while sending notification by JavaPNS

Tags: java, iphone, ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

while sending push notification by JavaPNS, an exception occurred with below message.

> Exception in thread "JavaPNS grouped notification thread in LIST mode"
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

I guess the reason is because of that I tried to send the notifications to too many users by 1 time.

```
public void send (List<Device> devices, Object keystore, String password, boolean production) {

       /* Prepare a simple payload to push */ 
        PushNotificationPayload payload = PushNotificationPayload.alert("Hello World!");


       /* Decide how many threads you want to create and use */ 
        int threads = 30;


       /* Start threads, wait for them, and get a list of all pushed notifications */ 
        List<PushedNotification> notifications = Push.payload(payload, keystore, password, production, threads, devices);


}
```

I put 73,889 device tokens to the List `devices` and received the exception.

Do you think I need to send the notification several times?
Does anybody have an idea about sending notificaion to a lot of people?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of 2 solutions to your problem:

1) send batches of ... say 20k

or

2) Increase your heap memory size

example:
java -Xms512m -Xmx512m

(do a search...)